# Invalid Binary Error

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, binaryfiles, ipa

An update for an already existing app I have was submitted this morning. The update was very minor barely any changes were made. Apple has now sent me this email stating..

the following issues must be corrected:..

**Invalid Bundle Structure - Your package contains a bundle with the following issue: IPA bundle does not include a Payload directory.**

How do I fix this?

Comment: Which Xcode version are you using to archive the binary and upload it?

Comment: Also check the .ipa file in finder. Rename it to .zip. Unzip it. Check if payload folder is there or not. If payload is not there, archive again and upload it. If payload is there, upload it again. Its the problem while uploading. I had the same. Reuploading the binary solved the issue.

Comment: @Apurv I'm using the 5.1.1 and i did try reuploading SEVERAL times haha unfortunately it didn't help. I can't find any file with a .ipa extension? what would the file name be called? also no payload folder either.. I have 9 apps currently in the app store and i checked all project folders none have a payload folder and can't find anything with .ipa extension..What is it i could be doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried to re-archive the project again?

Comment: @holex with every resubmission re-archived

Comment: We are seeing the same thing, with a recent (forced) upgrade to XCode 5.1.1.  The IPA file is created if you create an enterprise / adhoc version.  https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/qa/qa1798/_index.html

Comment: @michaelpan i don't get the code signing part? am i suppose to use terminal?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, my answer has been deleted because it was not an answer to the question.
I do not have enough points to comment your question (that's what I tried to do because I obviously don't have the answer — just the same problem as you and trying to figure out why we're getting this Invalid Binary error)

As I said in my first post: I'll keep you up to date.
Today, I created a new Xcode project, with the same bundleID as the app I try to upload for a week now. It passes through the server-side pre-validation and I received a mail saying it's "Waiting for Review".
It answers one question I had since the beginning: It's not a server problem (I thought Apple had some issues with the pre-validation process).
I tried to play with architectures on this new project (for example, I only use armv7 arch for my App because of some incompatibility with third-part libraries). Still passes the server validation.

Then, I tried to copy the Info.plist file from my app to the new sample project which passes the server validation: BANG -> Invalid Binary!!
This info.plist is quite old, used since Xcode 3.0
I tried to remove some optional keys from it: still invalid binary
Then, I compared the original and needed keys with a new project's info.plist file : bang!
The "CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion" value was empty. On a new project, the value is "6.0".
I simply set "6.0" for CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion key and boom, it worked.
My guess is that Apple' servers are checking the info.plist file and needs a proper CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion value in order to read the .plist file. And I think it's not happening since Xcode 5.1.1, they must have updated their server among with the release of Xcode 5.1.1, that's all.

Jeez, I can't believe how dumb it was. It's a shame that Apple does not provide a comprehensive feedback.
Hope it will work for you! Let me know!

Comment: this solved our problem.  you need to have CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion in the info.plist file

Comment: yeay once i make this change though i no longer can use the simulators and reseting the content and settings for the simulator does not work? do you guys have this problem?

Comment: Weird for your simulator… no problem here.

Comment: also id like to say i don't think it has anything to do with OLD project files because the app i was having problems with was created no more then 2-3 months ago.. just thought id add that to this

Comment: Maybe Xcode 5.1.1 adds the correct version number then?

Comment: i have already value of CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion  is 6.0 but still apple said to me invalid binary

Comment: still having this error IPA bundle does not include a Payload directory.

Answer (score 5):

In my Info.plist, somehow my `Application requires iPhone environment` was set to `NO`.
setting it to `YES` fixed this...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

Just add the following item in your Info.plist:

LSRequiresIPhoneOS | Boolean | YES