# Invalid Bundle Structure - Does not include a Payload Directory

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle, payload

After I've uploaded binary to iTunes, I got "Invalid Binary" and this mail:

> Dear Developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issue with
> your recent delivery. To process your delivery, the following issue must be
> corrected: Invalid Bundle Structure - Your package contains a bundle
> with the following issue: IPA bundle does not include a Payload
> Directory. Once  these issues have been corrected, you can then
> redeliver the corrected binary.
>
> Regards, The App Store team

Used Software/Hardware
1)Game Maker Studio Professional
2)Xcode 5.1.1

Actually in this new version we have added

1. Facebook score Share
2. Twitter Score Share
3. Game Centre
4. Push-notification
5. and also added iAds with in-app-purchase to
   remove ads for 0.99$.

I don't know what is payload directory.

Can any one help us to solve this issue?

I've unsuccessfully tried:
[Invalid Binary Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194582/invalid-binary-error)

- I can not find payload folder in my archive
- I can not find "CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion" in my archive.

Comment: Do you a value for CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion in your info.plist?

Comment: Yes The info.plist inside the application folder has the dictionary version 6.0

Comment: any good luck @BharathRaj, i am facing same issue. kindly let me know if you found issue.

Answer (score 18):

Just add the following item in your Info.plist:

LSRequiresIPhoneOS | Boolean | YES

Without it, the archive export is building an iOS IPA file with the OSX Applications folder :)

Comment: Just to mention, this setting also needs to be set to YES even if the App you're trying to Archive is specifically for iPads.  (I incorrectly had it set to NO for this reason.)

Comment: This fixed my error. Its funny that apple being so user friendly can't show developer friendly error messages.

Comment: It works for me i was unable to upload on Hockeyapp and Daiwi but after that fix it works for me. after 2 hours this fix works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open your Info.plist file and click plus(+) and write Info Dictionary Version which is 6.0 and clean app and upload it Again. now you get clear Idea.